# Yii2.0 first button with e.preventDefault and second button will not fire up

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have this code below,if I put e.preventDefault in my compute button,after clicking the compute button,then clicking the savebutton,the savebutton will not trigger I need to click again so that it will fire up the event.I don't know why it behaves like this.

views  mysite\index

```
 $comp = "
         $('#compute').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();//If I remove this, my second submit button will fire up.
            console.log('compute');

           });
";
$this->registerJs($comp, View::POS_READY, 'my-comp');
```

Here is my form.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'horizontal']); ?>

       <?= $form->field($model, 'amount', ['options' => ['width' => '20%']]) ?>
        <?= Button::widget([
            'id'=>'compute',
            'label' => 'Compute',
            'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-md'],
        ]); ?>


    //here is my submit button,it will not fire up if my button compute has e.preventDefault();

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spaid" class="control-label col-sm-3 sr-only">paid</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','id'=>'savecompute']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: where is your other button click function (savecompute)/. Please add that code too.

Comment: In savecompute I did not use jquery for that it is just normal submit

Comment: I don't know the problem either. What is the html that the browser gets? Can you post this? Is there any other relevant code? You could also try to put the compute button outside the form. Then at least it should have nothing to do with the form anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have orphan closing tag of my form and div,that's why it behaves like that...my solution is to fixed those orphan closing tags and it works.